# Unable to compile using additional library/jar file, javac classpath

Tags: java, jar, javac

I am trying to compile code with javac using the ojdbc6.jar from oracle.

I have my source in 'src' my .class in 'bin' and my 'jar' in includes.

my current javac command is:

```
javac -cp ".;./includes/ojdbc6.jar" src/*.java -d bin
```

this worked until I imported the driver in one of my source files. Now I get:

```
javac -cp ".;./includes/ojdbc6.jar" src/*.java -d bin
src/OracleSingleton.java:1: package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;
```

I am sure the problem is with my classpath, any idea how to fix this. I have manually checked to see whether the file is there and it is.

also seeing as I haven't got this far I might as well preempt the next question, do I have to point to this jar when running the program too? if so how.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you on Windows or a unix-like system (Linux, Mac, Solaris, *BSD)? In the latter case you'll need `:` instead of `;` as path separator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I see the problem, but here's a working example that might shed some light. I got the driver [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html).

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

class DriveTest {
    public static void main (String args [])
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Current JDBC Drivers: "
            + System.getProperty("jdbc.drivers"));
        Enumeration e = DriverManager.getDrivers(); 
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(e.nextElement());
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ javac -cp .:ojdbc6.jar DriveTest.java 
$ java -cp .:ojdbc6.jar DriveTest
Current JDBC Drivers: null
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@2666e815
$ jar tf ojdbc6.jar | grep OracleDriver
oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver$1.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriverExtension.class
```

Addendum:

Looking closer, the [`DriverManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) [*Service Provider*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) mechanism specifies `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`. You should use that instead of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`.

```
$ cat META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver 
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use -classpath instead of cp, that should solve the problem

Comment: Is there any reason to think this might [help](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javac/index.html)? Either form appears to be correct.